# Unexpected behaviour while referencing and dereferencing array with pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Here is the code:

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int* p = (int*)(&a + 1);
printf("%d, %d", (*a+1), *(p - 1));\
// output 2, 5
```

As I believe `p` points the second element in array `a`, which is 2. So the output of `*(p-1)` is 1.
But in VS `*(p-1)` output 5, what is the reason?
Thanks for helping!

I believe the output should be 2, 1.

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but I would find it clearer if the array were initialized with values like `{ 100, 200, 300, 400, 500 }` so that you don't confuse `(*a) + 1` with `*(a + 1)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question lies in the error message that you (probably) saw just before you inserted the `(int*)` cast to override the compiler's better judgement:

```
int* p = (&a + 1);

temp.cpp:7:10: error: cannot initialize a variable of type 'int *' with an rvalue of type 'int (*)[5]'
    int * q = &a;
```

Since `a` is of type `int[5]`, that means that `&a` is of type `pointer-to-int[5]`, and also it means that `sizeof(a)` is equal to `5*sizeof(int)`... which means that `(&a+1)` is pointing to the address after the end of the array (i.e. where the next array-of-5-ints would be if you had an array of arrays-of-5-ints-each), *not* to the second `int` in your array.

So when you evaluate `*(p-1)` in your code, you are taking a pointer to `&a[5]` (which doesn't exist, but nevermind that) and then subtracting 1 `int` from it, which gives you a pointer to `&a[4]`, which you dereference to get the value `5` from your array.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is identifier(variable a) of array i.e. a stores the pointer of starting of array itself

you have written (&a + 1) so it consider whole array as a pointer and +1 points p to next location after size of array

eg. array has addressed 100,104,108,112,116

&a+1   ->   120

use a+1 instead of &a+1

a+1   ->   104

so the new code will be

```
int a[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int* p = (int*)(a + 1);
printf("%d, %d", (*a+1), *(p - 1));
```

this gives expected output as 2,1

hope this clears doubt

more to say int *a and int a[] are somewhat similar in pointer but not exactly.